# Why does SSL Stream use a byte array of 2048?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tcp, tcpclient

After reading the [TCP SSL example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx), they use a byte array to read data into the stream. Is there a reason the array is limited to 2048? What if TCP sends a longer array than 2048? Also, how does the buffer.Length property continue to read the stream, as it is changing. It doesn't make complete sense to me. Why read the length of the buffer, wouldn't you want to read the length of the incremental bytes coming into the stream?

```
    static string ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
    {
        // Read the  message sent by the client.
        // The client signals the end of the message using the
        // "<EOF>" marker.
        byte [] buffer = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;
        do
        {
            // Read the client's test message.
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8
            // in case a character spans two buffers.
            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer,0,bytes)];
            decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars,0);
            messageData.Append (chars);
            // Check for EOF or an empty message.
            if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (bytes !=0); 

        return messageData.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading from any kind of Stream (not just `SslStream`) just because you asked for X bytes they are allowed to give you anywhere between 1 and X bytes back. that is what the `bytes` returned from `Read` is for, to see how many you read.

If you give `Read` a giant buffer it is only going to fill in the first few 1000ish bytes, giving it a bigger buffer is a waste of space. If you need more data than the buffer is large you make multiple requests for data.

A important thing to remember when dealing with network streams, one write on the sender does not mean one read on the receiver. Writes can be combined together or split apart at arbitrary points, that is why it is to have some form of [Message Framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) to be able to tell when you have "all the data". In the example you posted they use the marker `<EOF>` to signal "end of message".

Comment: Should I assume that the end of 1 message and the start of the next message, could be in the same array of bytes returned from the Read method? Like if they were to send multiple messages, the stream will read the trailing end of the first, and just a bit of the 2nd... meaning I would have to anticipate the <EOF> or <CR><LF> is in the middle of the array?

Comment: Correct, the example from the MSDN does not handle that case. It also fails horribly if a multi-byte charcactor gets split in to two separate reads. In the notes they say `Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8 in case a character spans two buffers.` however if that does happen all they do is throw away the first byte of the two bytes and not do anything to handle the extra byte on the next read causing every read thereafter to potentially be corrupted if many multi-byte characters where posted in a row.

Comment: Usually you rarely work with a NetworkStream or SslStream directly, you would normally feed it in to a `StreamReader` for text streams or a `BinaryReader` for binary streams, those handle the issues of "multiple messages per read" and "split messages per read" for you internally and you just read out your `String` from `StreamReader.ReadLine()`  or `int` from `BinaryReader.ReadInt32()`

Comment: Do you have any good references that would explain how to use a StreamReader with SslStream? Would I use StreamReader or BinaryReader? This very interesting. Ok I'm done marking your question as the answer thanks.

Comment: Not really, just find any guide on how to use a StreamReader. That is the point of abstractions, it could be a SslStream, a NetworkStream, or a FileStream it does not change how you use the StreamReader.

Comment: For the first time I understand what the streamreaders are for!